# Difference between sine and cosine driven oscillators

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators

For a driven damped oscillator, my book only shows the solution for the driving force being a term of cos(t). However, in Fourier Series, the force may have terms of sin(t). How do I convert the cosine solution for the position x(t) into a solution for sines? If needed, the book is "Classical Mechanics" by John R. Taylor.

Comment: $cos(x)=sin(x+\pi /2)$

Comment: Yes, but could you be more detailed? What is the difference in x(t)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sine and cosine are the same curve, only shifted, so a phase difference transforms one into the other. For instance, wherever you have $\cos (\omega t +\psi)$ you replace it with $\sin (\omega t +\psi+\pi/2)$

Comment: Thank you for the more clear answer, it is very helpful!

Comment: @ElliottTanner, if you found a satisfactory answer, I recommend you to click the check mark next to the answer.